# Listing folders on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kotlin

just trying to parse and display a whole bucket, i can't get rid off the message no suchKeyException which is odd ..

The code below is connecting and displaying to standard out:

```
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider
    import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.EncodingType
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Response
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.paginators.ListObjectsV2Iterable
    import java.net.URI

    internal class S3ObjectsOps {

    companion object {

            private val BUCKET: String = "mybucket"
            private val REGION_IRE = software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region.EU_WEST_1

            val s3c = S3Client.builder()
                    .region(REGION_IRE)
                    .endpointOverride(URI("https://${BUCKET}.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"))
                    .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder()
                            .profileName("default")
                            .build())
                    .build()

            fun lsfolders(bucket: String) {
                val listReq = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
                        .bucket(bucket)
                        .delimiter("/")
                        .prefix("")
                        .maxKeys(10_000)
                        .build()

                val listRes = s3c.listObjectsV2Paginator(listReq)

                listRes.contents().onEach { f ->
                    if (!f.key().isNullOrBlank()) {
                        println(">> ${f.key()}")
                    } else {
                        println(" = ")
                    }
                }

            }

            @JvmStatic
            fun main(args: Array<String>) {
                val bucket: String = ((args.size > 0 && !args[0].isNullOrEmpty()).toString()) ?: BUCKET
                println("s3 ls test for bucket ${bucket}")
                lsfolders(bucket)
            }
        }

    }
```

Which raises:

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException: The specified key does not exist. (Service: S3Client; Status Code: 404; Request ID: C8AF9CB788D77F74)
>   Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException: The specified key does not exist. (Service: S3Client; Status Code: 404; Request ID: C8AF9CB788D77F74)
>       at software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleErrorResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:114)

Same Exception using a stream

```
   listRes.contents().stream().forEach { content -> println(" Key: " + content.key() + " | ") }
```

Thanks folks !

Comment: The S3 [access log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) for the bucket should have an entry with request-id matching `C8AF9CB788D77F74` which will tell you about the actual request sent to the service that triggered the exception.  Probably unrelated, `maxKeys()` maximum value is 1000.  I *suspect* larger values are silently coerced to 1000.

Comment: What’s the purpose of ‘endpointOverride’ for the s3Client builder? I think that’s causing the error. The Endpoint is different than your bucket url.

Comment: Thanks Diego your remarkshowed me the path, in fact the pbl was due to the ListObjectsV2Request which calls the target bucket, it made a coflict with bucket call s3c.

Answer (score 0):

The right calls of ListObjectsV2Request is:

```
val listReq = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .delimiter("/")
                .build()

        val listRes = s3c.listObjectsV2Paginator(listReq)
        listRes.contents().stream().forEach { content -> println(" Key: " + content.key() + " | ") }
```

Then, s3client must init with mimimum params:

```
   val s3c = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName("default").build())
            .region(REGION_IRE)
            .build()
```